# bug in installing pyinstaller

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

So I tried the `pip install pyinstaller` command and thats what happened:

So I had this bug:

```
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached pyinstaller-4.1.tar.gz (3.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\aris\onedrive\υπολογιστής\python\python.exe' 'c:\users\aris\onedrive\υπολογιστής\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\aris\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_o2ged7z'
         cwd: C:\Users\aris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ipo7dr00\pyinstaller_7b00b43eae9b4a19be431faa4f4cf9f4
    Complete output (38 lines):
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf5 in position 0: invalid start byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\aris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tgdlk_61\pyinstaller.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\aris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tgdlk_61\pyinstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\aris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tgdlk_61\pyinstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to C:\Users\aris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tgdlk_61\pyinstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\aris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tgdlk_61\pyinstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\aris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tgdlk_61\pyinstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\aris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tgdlk_61\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\aris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tgdlk_61\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'pyinstaller-gui.py'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\_sdks'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.vagrant'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader\.lock-waf*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching 'news\_template.rst'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'news'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests\scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found anywhere in distribution
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\aris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tgdlk_61\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\aris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tgdlk_61\pyinstaller.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\aris\onedrive\υπολογιστής\python\python.exe' 'c:\users\aris\onedrive\υπολογιστής\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\aris\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_o2ged7z' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Does anyone know how I can solve it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says:

```
error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel' ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\aris\onedrive\υπολογιστής\python\python.exe'
```

Try installing `wheel` first. mostly the error describes itself. try going through them carefully, it will save you lot of debugging time.
Run this command:

```
pip install wheel
```

Let me know if the error still exists.

Comment: It does not, I fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Install the `wheel` package first. While you're at it, upgrade the whole pip "stack":

```
python -m pip install -U wheel setuptools pip
```